# Dynamic paint Displace not rendering

Tags: physics, eevee-render-engine, dynamic-paint

I have been trying for the past couple of hours to render an animation with dynamic paint displace, but while it works in the viewport, it does not show up in the render. These are a few things I have tried so far:

Check that the Canvas has enabled 'show in render'.
I don't have a subdivision surface modifier.

It works well in the preview, but when I try rendering it, the displacement on the mesh won't show. Does anyone have any possible solutions for this?

If it makes any difference, I'm trying to render it with Eevee on blender 2.81.

Answer (score 0):

It was a dumb mistake, it turns out. I had rendered it without baking it. And when I baked it and then rendered it, it was rendering the image sequence I had previously rendered, so no changes were being displayed. It has been fixed now.

Comment: Wait so you just baked it? It's not working for me.