# Snow Simulation Particle Accrual Problem

Tags: particles, dynamic-paint

I'm trying out a winter scene. I figured I'd follow [this tutorial by CG Geek](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFVsfYCMJGE).

The aim of the project is to create snowfall and then have that snowfall paint the ground layer as well as apply displacement to simulate snow accrual.

Per my usual experience with particles, they aren't working right. I have set everything up and baked it. And when I view my scene in Rendered View, everything looks great. When I actually render out a frame, however, none of the snow painting or accumulation shows up.

[Here is the rather large BLEND file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LTvH10C9ExAQ7ZWfcuTgDUUweTjNOtib/view?usp=sharing) if you'd like to brave this. I'm happy to post pics of particular parts of the blend - or post variables from within it - if there is a need.

Thanks for your attention.

**Update:** I reloaded the scene and confirmed that all of the following elements have (and had) completed bakes for the full length of the sim:

- Dynamic Paint - 01 Surface Hit (when the snow hits the ground and 'paints' the alternate (snow) material.
- Dynamic Paint - 02 Surface Pile Up (when the snow accumulates)
- Particle System - Snow Emission (snowfall)

And since this  scene is in eevee, I have baked the lighting.

Is there some other thing I need to bake? Because here is the output AFTER I deleted the bakes and then Baked All Dynamics.

First, what I see in Rendered view in my 3d Viewport:
[image]

But here is what I see when I actually render out the frame:
[image]

And what kills me is that there is accumulation on the 'duck' material, but not on any other material. But that accumulation is just 'more of the first material' and not the snow.

And my materials are set up exactly the same so that everything on the mesh 'responds'. This is the node setup for each mat:
[image]

The top shader connector goes to the 'before' material and the bottom connects to the 'after' (snow covered) material with the dynamic paint as the factor.

Comment: I can't seem to access the google drive.

Comment: It is set to be downloadable by anyone. I just confirmed. Sorry you are encountering difficulty.

Comment: Working now, wifi must have been wack.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161760/dynamic-paint-displace-not-rendering Found a person with the same problem, apparently, they just forgot to bake it>

Comment: Yeah I just did a full bake from the start of the animation and it worked, hopefully it works for you.

Comment: Really? Oh, I baked it. I baked the heck out of it. Grrr. I will RE-bake everything. Again. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Confirmed that everything is baked and... doesn't work. Same problem. I provided more detail in the main post.